# limit seat selection - jQuery-Seat-Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working with the library, jQuery-Seat-Charts. I need to make it possible to mark only one place and not several. I could hide the DIV of all the numbers or disable the click on them but I don't know how to do it with this javascript library.

[image]

As you will see in the image I have number 16 marked and if I continue clicking on the numbers it lets me continue marking more.

How can I make it not allow to select more numbers of places?

```
<ul id="selected-seats"></ul>
                
                Total: <b>$<span id="total">0</span></b>



<script>
        var firstSeatLabel = 1;
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $cart = $('#selected-seats'),
                $counter = $('#counter'),
                $total = $('#total'),
                sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
                map: [
                    'ff_ff',
                    'ff_ff',
                    'ee_ee',
                    'ee_ee',
                    'ee___',
                    'ee_ee',
                    'ee_ee',
                    'ee_ee',
                    'eeeee',
                ],
                seats: {
                    f: {
                        price   : 100,
                        classes : 'first-class', //your custom CSS class
                        category: 'First Class'
                    },
                    e: {
                        price   : 40,
                        classes : 'economy-class', //your custom CSS class
                        category: 'Economy Class'
                    }                   
                
                },
                naming : {
                    top : false,
                    getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
                        return firstSeatLabel++;
                    },
                },
                legend : {
                    node : $('#legend'),
                    items : [
                        [ 'f', 'available',   'First Class' ],
                        [ 'e', 'available',   'Economy Class'],
                        [ 'f', 'unavailable', 'Already Booked']
                    ]                   
                },
                click: function () {
                    if (this.status() == 'available') {
                        //let's create a new <li> which we'll add to the cart items
                        $('<li class="circulos">'+this.settings.label+',</li>')
                            .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                            .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                            .appendTo($cart);
                        
                        /*
                         * Lets update the counter and total
                         *
                         * .find function will not find the current seat, because it will change its stauts only after return
                         * 'selected'. This is why we have to add 1 to the length and the current seat price to the total.
                         */
                        $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
                        $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)+this.data().price);
                        
                        return 'selected';
                    } else if (this.status() == 'selected') {
                        //update the counter
                        $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                        //and total
                        $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)-this.data().price);
                    
                        //remove the item from our cart
                        $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();
                    
                        //seat has been vacated
                        return 'available';
                    } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') {
                        //seat has been already booked
                        return 'unavailable';
                    } else {
                        return this.style();
                    }
                }
            });

            //this will handle "[cancel]" link clicks
            $('#selected-seats').on('click', '.cancel-cart-item', function () {
                //let's just trigger Click event on the appropriate seat, so we don't have to repeat the logic here
                sc.get($(this).parents('li:first').data('seatId')).click();
            });

            //let's pretend some seats have already been booked
            sc.get(['1_2', '4_1', '7_1', '7_2']).status('unavailable');

            $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#enviar").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url : 'procesar-asiento',
                data: { id: $('#selected-seats').text() }
            })
        
        });
    });
    
    
    });

    function recalculateTotal(sc) {
        var total = 0;
    
        //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
        sc.find('selected').each(function () {
            total += this.data().price;
        });
        
        return total;
    }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take two variables for booked seat and max allow seat number. like below
// Max seat allow is only 1 for me.
let maxSeatAllowNumber = 1;
let bookedSeat = 0;

And then do increment and decrement value for bookedSeat variable in the click function. increment it in the available status condition and decrement it in the selected status.

And last, add the below condition in the available status in the click function.

```
if (bookedSeat >= maxSeatAllowNumber) {
      return; alert(`Only ${maxSeatAllowNumber} seat allow to book at once.`);
   }
```

Thats it.

Below I am adding the whole script for reference.

```
<script>
var firstSeatLabel = 1;
let maxSeatAllowNumber = 1;
let bookedSeat = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $cart = $('#selected-seats'),
    $counter = $('#counter'),
    $total = $('#total'),
    sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
      map: [
        'fff_fff',
        'fff_fff',
        'eee_eee',
        'eee_eee',
        'ee___ee',
        'eee_eee',
        'eee_eee',
        'eee_eee',
        'eeeeeee',
      ],
      seats: {
        f: {
          price: 100,
          classes: 'first-class', //your custom CSS class
          category: 'First Class'
        },
        e: {
          price: 40,
          classes: 'economy-class', //your custom CSS class
          category: 'Economy Class'
        }

      },
      naming: {
        top: false,
        getLabel: function (character, row, column) {
          console.log(character, row, column);
          return firstSeatLabel++;
        },
      },
      legend: {
        node: $('#legend'),
        items: [
          ['f', 'available', 'First Class'],
          ['e', 'available', 'Economy Class'],
          ['f', 'unavailable', 'Already Booked']
        ]
      },
      click: function () {
        if (this.status() == 'available') {
          if (bookedSeat >= maxSeatAllowNumber) {
            alert(`Only ${maxSeatAllowNumber} seat allow to book at once.`);
            return;
          }
          //let's create a new <li> which we'll add to the cart items
          $('<li>' + this.data().category + ' Seat # ' + this.settings.label + ': <b>$' + this.data().price + '</b> <a href="#" class="cancel-cart-item">[cancel]</a></li>')
            .attr('id', 'cart-item-' + this.settings.id)
            .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
            .appendTo($cart);

          /*
           * Lets update the counter and total
           *
           * .find function will not find the current seat, because it will change its stauts only after return
           * 'selected'. This is why we have to add 1 to the length and the current seat price to the total.
           */
          $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length + 1);
          $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc) + this.data().price);
          bookedSeat++;
          return 'selected';
        } else if (this.status() == 'selected') {
          //update the counter
          $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length - 1);
          //and total
          $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc) - this.data().price);

          //remove the item from our cart
          $('#cart-item-' + this.settings.id).remove();
          bookedSeat--;
          //seat has been vacated
          return 'available';
        } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') {
          //seat has been already booked
          return 'unavailable';
        } else {
          return this.style();
        }
      }
    });

  //this will handle "[cancel]" link clicks
  $('#selected-seats').on('click', '.cancel-cart-item', function () {
    //let's just trigger Click event on the appropriate seat, so we don't have to repeat the logic here
    sc.get($(this).parents('li:first').data('seatId')).click();
  });

  //let's pretend some seats have already been booked
  sc.get(['1_2', '4_1', '7_1', '7_2']).status('unavailable');

});

function recalculateTotal(sc) {
  var total = 0;

  //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
  sc.find('selected').each(function () {
    total += this.data().price;
  });

  return total;
}
```

If you have still problem with it let me know.